# How can I return the response data from Auth0's API on my API?

Tags: javascript, axios, auth0

I'm calling Auth0's API with axios to fetch a list of users. I'm trying to return them using the syntax that I'm using this syntax:

```
.then(res => {
  console.log(res.data) // Prints the deired result
  return res.status(200).json(res.data);
})
```

res.data is printing the desired result. But I'm getting and empty response body on Postman.

I also tried `return res.data`, only to get a timeout.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling the `status` method on the Axios [response](https://github.com/axios/axios#response-schema) object when it should be called on the Express [response](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res) object.

You should name the Auth0 API response something other than `res` to make sure `res` inside the callback refers to the Express [response](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res) object. Or better use destructuring. And you don't have to set the `200` status code since it is set automatically.

```js
.then(({ data }) => res.json(data))
```